# Alternative to esc_textarea

Tags: metabox, validation, esc-textarea

I need an alternative function to use with textareas in meta boxes instead of esc_textarea.

The problem is that when I use this function with textarea's it removes line breaks and paragraphs. Is there an alternative function that will keep the line breaks and paragraphs.

I have tried the validation reference page in the Codex but had no luck finding a function.

Answer (score 2):

`esc_textarea` shouldn't strip out newlines -- It's just a thin wrapper around `htmlspecialchars`: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2536

```
<?php
function esc_textarea( $text ) {
    $safe_text = htmlspecialchars( $text, ENT_QUOTES );
    return apply_filters( 'esc_textarea', $safe_text, $text );
}
```

That said, there are lots of options.  What do you want your users to do have the ability to post?  [`esc_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) will escape all special characters (just like `esc_textarea`). `esc_attr(strip_tags($stuff));` is a favorite combination of mine.

You should also have a look at the [data validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) page in the codex.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delay but this was the solution I used. Thanks for the feedback.

```
$value = esc_html($value);
$value = html_entity_decode($value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`wpautop`](http://look4wp.com/wpautop) before `esc_textarea`, like this:

```
echo esc_textarea( wpautop( $value ) );
```

Comment: `autop` will insert HTML that `esc_textarea` will then escape (convert to character entities), so that's probably not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$lines = "Hello !
From this new line.
";
echo nl2br($lines);
echo esc_textarea(nl2br($lines));
```

For me, the output is (but the content-type is `text/plain`):

```
Hello !<br />
From this new line.<br />
Hello !&lt;br /&gt;
From this new line.&lt;br /&gt;
```

I suggest to you to set your content-type with 'text/plain' before.

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

If the content type is by default set to 'text/html', the result will be:

```
Hello !
From this new line.
Hello !<br /> From this new line.<br />
```